# Wheel picker on dialog box android

Tags: android, dialog

I want to get text from spin wheel as password. Can you please give me any example of spin wheel for getting text from it. I didn't get any good example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're asking? What do you mean by a spin wheel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

I was trying to get this spin wheel at last I have build my wheel for getting the texts from the users. I am giving a example for four integers.

```
 package com.example.wheel;

 import kankan.wheel.widget.ArrayWheelAdapter;
 import kankan.wheel.widget.OnWheelChangedListener;
 import kankan.wheel.widget.OnWheelScrollListener;
 import kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView;
 import android.R.color;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.Dialog;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.Window;
 import android.widget.Button;

public class Wheelboxtcr extends Dialog implements
    android.view.View.OnClickListener {

String wheelMenu1[] = new String[] { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6",
        "7", "8", "9" };
/*String wheelMenu2[] = new String[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G",
        "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T",
        "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z" };*/

boolean wheelScrolled = false;
public Activity c;
public Dialog d;
public Button button;

public Wheelboxtcr(Activity a) {
    super(a);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.c = a;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(color.transparent);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.wheellayouttcr);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
    initWheel1(R.id.p1);
    initWheel2(R.id.p2);
    initWheel3(R.id.p3);
    initWheel4(R.id.p4);

}

OnWheelScrollListener scrolledListener = new OnWheelScrollListener() {
    public void onScrollStarts(WheelView wheel) {
        wheelScrolled = true;
    }

    public void onScrollEnds(WheelView wheel) {
        wheelScrolled = false;
        updateStatus();
    }
};

// Wheel changed listener
private final OnWheelChangedListener changedListener = new OnWheelChangedListener() {
    public void onChanged(WheelView wheel, int oldValue, int newValue) {
        if (!wheelScrolled) {
            updateStatus();
        }
    }
};

/**
 * Updates entered PIN status
 */
private void updateStatus() {
    // Main.text3.setText(wheelMenu2[getWheel(R.id.p3).getCurrentItem()]);

}

private void initWheel1(int id) {
    WheelView wheel = (WheelView) findViewById(id);

    wheel.setAdapter(new ArrayWheelAdapter<String>(wheelMenu1));
    wheel.setVisibleItems(2);
    wheel.setCurrentItem(0);
    wheel.addChangingListener(changedListener);
    wheel.addScrollingListener(scrolledListener);
}

private void initWheel2(int id) {
    WheelView wheel = (WheelView) findViewById(id);

    wheel.setAdapter(new ArrayWheelAdapter<String>(wheelMenu1));
    wheel.setVisibleItems(2);
    wheel.setCurrentItem(0);
    wheel.addChangingListener(changedListener);
    wheel.addScrollingListener(scrolledListener);
}

private void initWheel3(int id) {
    WheelView wheel = (WheelView) findViewById(id);

    wheel.setAdapter(new ArrayWheelAdapter<String>(wheelMenu1));
    wheel.setVisibleItems(2);
    wheel.setCurrentItem(0);
    wheel.addChangingListener(changedListener);
    wheel.addScrollingListener(scrolledListener);
}

private void initWheel4(int id) {
    WheelView wheel = (WheelView) findViewById(id);

    wheel.setAdapter(new ArrayWheelAdapter<String>(wheelMenu1));
    wheel.setVisibleItems(2);
    wheel.setCurrentItem(0);
    wheel.addChangingListener(changedListener);
    wheel.addScrollingListener(scrolledListener);
}


private WheelView getWheel(int id) {
    return (WheelView) findViewById(id);
}

private int getWheelValue(int id) {
    return getWheel(id).getCurrentItem();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn: {
        String s = wheelMenu1[getWheel(R.id.p1).getCurrentItem()]
                + wheelMenu1[getWheel(R.id.p2).getCurrentItem()]
                + wheelMenu1[getWheel(R.id.p3).getCurrentItem()]
                + wheelMenu1[getWheel(R.id.p4).getCurrentItem()]
                ;

        Display.jno.setText(s);
        break;
    }

    default:
        break;
    }
    dismiss();
}
}
```

It's layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="103dp"
android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

    <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView
        android:id="@+id/p1"
        android:layout_width="33dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView
        android:id="@+id/p2"
        android:layout_width="33dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView
        android:id="@+id/p3"
        android:layout_width="33dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView
        android:id="@+id/p4"
        android:layout_width="33dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Set"
        android:textColor="#eaa932"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Does your widget work with only one listener for each? Because when I have multiple kankan widgets and add the same listener to all, it only works for one