# UI Picker in Android

Tags: android, datepicker, picker

**I want to build a custom item picker like this**

[image]

I would like to hear any ideas about how to build this thing I tried with time picker but I guess this is not the right approach.

Comment: check out this  code may help full :https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-wheel/downloads

Comment: just give try to search on google atleast

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833827/wheel-picker-on-dialog-box-android

Answer (score 2):

Boris,

You should use android material picker, here is android library 
- https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker

If you want to make ios type picker view you can user this library 
- https://github.com/AigeStudio/WheelPicker

Answer (score 1):

This is called [wheel  picker](http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2011/06/android-wheel-picker-example.html)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
    {
        // TODO: Externalize string-array
        String wheelMenu1[] = new String[]{"name 1", "name 2", "name 3", "name 4", "name 5", "name 6","name 7","name 8","name 9"};
        String wheelMenu2[] = new String[]{"age 1", "age 2", "age 3"};
        String wheelMenu3[] = new String[]{"10", "20","30","40","50","60"};

        // Wheel scrolled flag
        private boolean wheelScrolled = false;

        private TextView text;
        private EditText text1;
        private EditText text2;
        private EditText text3;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);

                initWheel1(R.id.p1);
                initWheel2(R.id.p2);
                initWheel3(R.id.p3);

                text1 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.r1);
                text2 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.r2);
                text3 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.r3);
                text = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.result);
            }

        // Wheel scrolled listener
        OnWheelScrollListener scrolledListener = new OnWheelScrollListener()
            {
                public void onScrollStarts(WheelView wheel)
                    {
                        wheelScrolled = true;
                    }

                public void onScrollEnds(WheelView wheel)
                    {
                        wheelScrolled = false;
                        updateStatus();
                    }
            };

        // Wheel changed listener
        private final OnWheelChangedListener changedListener = new OnWheelChangedListener()
            {
                public void onChanged(WheelView wheel, int oldValue, int newValue)
                    {
                        if (!wheelScrolled)
                            {
                                updateStatus();
                            }
                    }
            };

        /**
         * Updates entered PIN status
         */
        private void updateStatus()
            {
                text1.setText(wheelMenu1[getWheel(R.id.p1).getCurrentItem()]);
                text2.setText(wheelMenu2[getWheel(R.id.p2).getCurrentItem()]);
                text3.setText(wheelMenu3[getWheel(R.id.p3).getCurrentItem()]);

                text.setText(wheelMenu1[getWheel(R.id.p1).getCurrentItem()] + " - " + wheelMenu2[getWheel(R.id.p2).getCurrentItem()] + " - " + wheelMenu3[getWheel(R.id.p3).getCurrentItem()]);
            }

        /**
         * Initializes wheel
         *
         * @param id
         *          the wheel widget Id
         */

        private void initWheel1(int id)
            {
                WheelView wheel = (WheelView) findViewById(id);
                wheel.setAdapter(new ArrayWheelAdapter<String>(wheelMenu1));
                wheel.setVisibleItems(2);
                wheel.setCurrentItem(0);
                wheel.addChangingListener(changedListener);
                wheel.addScrollingListener(scrolledListener);
            }

        private void initWheel2(int id)
            {
                WheelView wheel = (WheelView) findViewById(id);
                wheel.setAdapter(new ArrayWheelAdapter<String>(wheelMenu2));
                wheel.setVisibleItems(2);
                wheel.setCurrentItem(0);
                wheel.addChangingListener(changedListener);
                wheel.addScrollingListener(scrolledListener);
            }

        private void initWheel3(int id)
            {
                WheelView wheel = (WheelView) findViewById(id);

                wheel.setAdapter(new ArrayWheelAdapter<String>(wheelMenu3));
                wheel.setVisibleItems(2);
                wheel.setCurrentItem(0);
                wheel.addChangingListener(changedListener);
                wheel.addScrollingListener(scrolledListener);
            }

        /**
         * Returns wheel by Id
         *
         * @param id
         *          the wheel Id
         * @return the wheel with passed Id
         */
        private WheelView getWheel(int id)
            {
                return (WheelView) findViewById(id);
            }

        /**
         * Tests wheel value
         *
         * @param id
         *          the wheel Id
         * @param value
         *          the value to test
         * @return true if wheel value is equal to passed value
         */
        private int getWheelValue(int id)
            {
                return getWheel(id).getCurrentItem();
            }
    }
```

Also Check this [demo](https://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam;jsessionid=811211D4FC4E6FD4EB4CC4BB3B7E8E8C?recipeId=883)

[image]